# AVCaptureMetadataOutput how to tell when face detection has lost the face and frame is empty

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, face-detection, avcapturesession

My ultimate goal is to only enable the photo capture button when a face is actually detected in the frame. Adding face detection using AVCaptureMetadataOutput is really simple, but I am having trouble finding a way to tell when the frame is empty. The AVCaptureMetadataOutput only has the one delegate method, DidOutputMetadataObjects and it is only called when the AVCaptureMetadataOutput detects an object, not when there is no object. I need a method that continually fires every second or so, or I need a way to check the detected objects within a timer.

I need something like:

```
IsFaceDetected () {
    isButtonEnabled = metadataOutput.IsDetectingObject();
}
```

or

```
new Timer(repeat 1000ms) {
    if (metadataOutput.DetectedObject == Object.Face) {
         buttonEnabled == true;
    } else {
         buttonEnabled == false;
    }
}
```

Has anyone discovered a way to make something like this work?

Answer (score 1):

Well I was unable to really find a way to do what I wanted so I just resorted to adding a single use timer to the end to the end of the callback method to disable the button IF the callback method was not called again.

```
    public void DidOutputMetadataObjects(AVCaptureMetadataOutput captureOutput,
    AVMetadataObject[] metadataObjects, AVCaptureConnection connection)
    {
        // dispose of the existing timer if there is one
        _timer?.Dispose();

        if (metadataObjects.OfType<AVMetadataFaceObject>() != null) {
            Button.Enabled = true;
        } else {
            Button.Enabled = false;
        }

        // have the timer disable the button if no face is detected again
        _timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback((object state) => {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                Button.Enabled = true;
            });
        }), null, 150, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

Comment: a better approach, instead of using a timer, use the FaceID you get from the metadata object.

Comment: Problem with that solution is that when a face goes out of frame, the API takes a good 20 seconds before it calls DidOutputMetadataObjects again passing 0 AVMetadataFaceObjects. I need to find out that information as soon as there are no more faces detected. Also for my requirements I need no faces vs. some faces, the FaceID is not particularly important for me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: In my code DidOutputMetadataObjects is called on every frame, not every 20 seconds. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Interesting. Is it being called when you move it so there is not a face detected? I do get the call back on every frame when a face is detected, but as soon as there is not one, no callback.

Comment: Every frame, face or no face. You can see the code here: https://github.com/BruelAndKjaer/Chafu/blob/master/Chafu/BaseCameraView.cs#L535

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation on this Tomasz, I will give my code another look and report back.